# How to update values of a dictionary in a json file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to add user info to a nested dictionary within a json file. Here's the code.

```
import json

dictionary = {'name': 'Tony Stark', 'attributes': ['genius', 'billionaire', 'playboy', 'philanthropist']}

with open('info.json', 'a+') as file:
    json.dump(dictionary, file)
```

The info.json file

```
{'marvel': [
        {'name': 'Bill Gates', 'attributes': ['philanthropist', 'programmer']}
    ]
}
```

Now, I am unable to dump the dictionary as a value for marvel which is a list. I'm trying to make it dynamic, adding Tony Stark's info to the json file.
Please help me with that, thanks.

Comment: The sane way is to deseralize your json, then modify the python object, then re-dump your json, overwriting the previous file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative:

```
import json

dictionary = {'name': 'Tony Stark', 'attributes': ['genius', 'billionaire', 'playboy', 'philanthropist']}

def write_json(data, filename='file.json'): 
    # function to add to JSON 
    with open(filename,'w') as f: 
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4) 

with open('file.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
    data['marvel'].append(dictionary) # appending data to Marvel 

write_json(data)
```

Edited as per observation of [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)

Comment: This is fine, although `temp = data['marvel']` doesn't seem to do anything, you can just do `data['marvel'].append(dictionary)`

Comment: Thank you, @juanpa.arrivillaga ! Added to the answer. Always room for improvement!